# Selectively deactivate pretty-print in jsoup for certain regions in a document

Tags: java, jsoup, pretty-print

When cleaning HTML documents with ***jsoup*** I like the fact that it automatically applies pretty-printing. I know I can deactivate it on a per-document basis, but I like to apply it for most of the document with the exception of certain problematic regions in which jsoup does not do a good job.

An example would be `DIV` tags with [CSS specifying `white-space: pre-wrap;`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/), i.e. semantically they behave like `PRE` tags, which means that the browser will be sensitive to line feeds and other whitespace (indentation). It gets worse if inside those regions there are more tags like `BR`, `SPAN` etc. because pretty-printing is applied and destroys the intended formatting of those regions.

So instead of deactivating pretty-printing completely for the whole HTML document, I like to selectively deactivate it whenever the parser meets something like `div.listing` (yes, I know the CSS class name of the problematic region) and retain the original HTML there. How would I go about implementing this?

**Update:** I forgot to mention that I print the cleaned document using

```java
output.print(document);
```

where `output` is a `PrintStream` and `document` is the jsoup `Document` instance. So if there is a better way to output the document, I am also open for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing, because I got no answer here so far and found no better solution either, is horrible, but it works:

1. **Parse** + clean document
2. Get (via `toString()`) + preserve pretty-printed HTML content
3. Deactivate pretty-printing, then get (via `toString()`) + **re-parse** content in original formatting into temporary document
4. **Re-parse** pretty-printed content from step 2 and assign to original document (overwriting it), then deactivate pretty-printing for the newly assigned document
5. Replace content for which pretty-printing would destroy formatting (e.g. elements with CSS `white-space: pre-wrap`) by preserved original from step 2 via iterating over both documents in parallel via something like

```java
for (int i = 0; i < elementsToBeFixed.size(); i++) 
  elementsToBeFixed.get(i).replaceWith(originalElements.get(i));
```

Conclusion: This is ugly because the same document which has already been parsed + cleaned up before needs to be re-parsed two more times, i.e. we have a total of 3 `Jsoup.parse(..)` calls. But - it works. `:-/`

I am still waiting for a better answer here, though.

Comment: Okay, after 9 months without a single comment or alternative answer, I am accepting my own workaround as an answer. My request on the mailing list also was not answered. So I am not expecting any progress there feature-wise. 